# Footer that moves with content

Tags: html, css

as the title suggests I have a footer that I want to move with my content. Basically, I have some text that when the browser is pushed to a smaller width the content goes under the footer, when I want the footer to rather move down with the content. Make it not just stay in a position.

I have gone through most of my code and removed positioning that is not needed, but if I try make it bottom 0 on the .footerwrap it floats somewhere randomly in the page. Hope you guys can help.

I'll link both my html and CSS so you can get an idea. Unfortunately, the site isn't live but it's probably a simple solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home</title>
<!--===================================================css links===================================================!-->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600,500,400,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,900,100,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="css/default_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<!--===================================================Header===================================================!-->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="headerwrap">
        <div class="social">
            <a href="www.facebook.com"><img class="move" src="images/deviant.png"></a>
            <a href="www.facebook.com"><img class="move" src="images/yt.png"/></a>
            <a href="www.facebook.com"><img class="move" src="images/fb.png"/></a>
        </div><!--close social!-->
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="images/logo.png" />
            </div><!--close logo-->
        </div><!--close header!-->
                    <div class="menu">
                <ul class="menutxt">
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="manga.html">CONTACT</a></li>                 
                </ul>
            </div><!--close menu!-->
    </div><!--close headerwrap!-->
<!--===================================================Fader===================================================!-->
<div class="fadewrapper">
    <div class="fader">
        <img class="bottom" src="images/dsas.png"/>
        <img class="top" src="images/dsa.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
<!--===================================================Content===================================================!-->
<div class="contentwrap">      
    <div class="textwrap">
        <div class="contentspace">
        </div><!--close contentspace!-->
        <div class="content">
            <p>Specializations</p>
            <p>With various skills in branding, multi-media 
            and advertising I am able to provide fresh and inspiring solutions 
            for the task given to me. Using various programs such as:</p>
        </div><!--close content!-->
        <div class="divider">
            <img src="images/divide.png"/>
        </div><!--close divider!-->
        <div class="content2">
            <p>Why me?</p>
            <p>The work I create is reflecting something
            fresh and exciting in order to meet the clients 
            needs. About pushing for new and innovative ideas 
            and pushing for an end result of brand and product growth</p>
        </div><!--close content2!-->
        <div class="contentspace">
        </div><!--close contentspace!-->
    </div><!--close textwrap!-->
</div><!--close contentwrap!-->
<!--===================================================Footer===================================================!-->
    <div class="footerwrap">
        <p class="foottxt">Designed and developed by Luke Babich- All Rights Reserved ©2015</p>
  </div><!--close footerwrap!-->
</div><!--close wrapper!-->
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
@charset "utf-8";
/*---------------------------- Body and Default ----------------------------*/
body {
    background:#171717;
    margin:0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color:#CCC;
} 
a{
    color:#000;
    transition:300ms;
}
a:hover {
    color:#000;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*---------------------------- Main Wrapper ----------------------------*/
.wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;    
}
/*---------------------------- Header ----------------------------*/
.headerwrap{
    position:relative;
    background:#171717;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px #333 ;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px #333 ;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px #000;
    z-index:200;
}
.header{
    position:relative;
    right:120px;
    min-height:180px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.logo{
    position: absolute;
    min-width:60px; 
    top:4%;
}
.logo img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:100%;
}
.social{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    min-width:20px; 
    top:15px;
    right:1%;
    z-index:500;    
}
.social img{
    float:right;
    width:35px;
    display: block;
    padding:0 0 0px 15px;
}
img.move {
    bottom:0px;
    transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.44, 1.2);
}
img.move:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale3d(1.4, 1.4, 1.4);    
}
/*---------------------------- Menu ----------------------------*/
.menu{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:200px;
    z-index:401;
}
ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0 0 5px 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li{
    display: inline;
    list-style:none;
    padding:1%;
    transition: all 300ms;
}
li a{
    color:#CCC;
    transition:300ms;
}
li a:hover {
    color:#900;
}
.menutxt{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size:1.8vw;
    font-weight:400;
    z-index:300;
}
/*---------------------------- Image Fader ----------------------------*/
.fader {
    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
}
.fader img {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  max-height:1000px;
  min-height:200px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
  @keyframes faderFadeInOut {
  0% {
  opacity:1;
    }
    45% {
    opacity:1;
    }
    55% {
    opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
    opacity:0;
    }
}
.fader img.top {
animation-name: faderFadeInOut;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 4s;
animation-direction: alternate;*/
}
/*---------------------------- Content ----------------------------*/
.contentwrap{   
    position:relative;
    top:500px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:500;
    background:#171717;
    height:290px;
    min-height:212px;   
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -10px 20px 0px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -10px 20px 0px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px -10px 10px 0px #000;
}
.textwrap{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    top:40px;
    height:190px;
}
.content,
.divider,
.content2 {
    text-align:center;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.divider{
    height:200px;
    width: 24%;
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1% 1% 0;
}
.divider img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.content,
.content2 {
    height:200px;
    width: 15%;
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1% 1% 0;
}
.contentspace{
    width: 20%;
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1% 1% 0;
}
/*---------------------------- Footer ----------------------------*/
.footerwrap{
    position:relative;
    top:460px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:501;
    clear:both;
}
.foottxt{
    width:100%;
    height:26px;    
    text-align: center;
    background:#333;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    padding-top:15px;
    font-size:0.5vw;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:200;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from using position:absolute and position:relative, some of the elemts had a fixed height and couldn't grow with the content and the .textwrap needed a clearfix.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/*---------------------------- Body and Default ----------------------------*/
body {
    background:#171717;
    margin:0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color:#CCC;
} 
a{
    color:#000;
    transition:300ms;
}
a:hover {
    color:#000;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*---------------------------- Main Wrapper ----------------------------*/
.wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;    
}
/*---------------------------- Header ----------------------------*/
.headerwrap{
    position:relative;
    background:#171717;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px #333 ;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px #333 ;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px #000;
    z-index:200;
}
.header{
    position:relative;
    right:120px;
    min-height:180px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.logo{
    position: absolute;
    min-width:60px; 
    top:4%;
}
.logo img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:100%;
}
.social{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    min-width:20px; 
    top:15px;
    right:1%;
    z-index:500;    
}
.social img{
    float:right;
    width:35px;
    display: block;
    padding:0 0 0px 15px;
}
img.move {
    bottom:0px;
    transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.44, 1.2);
}
img.move:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale3d(1.4, 1.4, 1.4);    
}
/*---------------------------- Menu ----------------------------*/
.menu{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:200px;
    z-index:401;
}
ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0 0 5px 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li{
    display: inline;
    list-style:none;
    padding:1%;
    transition: all 300ms;
}
li a{
    color:#CCC;
    transition:300ms;
}
li a:hover {
    color:#900;
}
.menutxt{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size:1.8vw;
    font-weight:400;
    z-index:300;
}
/*---------------------------- Image Fader ----------------------------*/
.fader {
    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
}
.fader img {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    max-height:1000px;
    min-height:200px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes faderFadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    45% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    55% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
.fader img.top {
    animation-name: faderFadeInOut;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-direction: alternate;*/
}
/*---------------------------- Content ----------------------------*/
.contentwrap{   
   /* position: relative */
    margin-top:500px; /* margin-top instead of top */
    width:100%;
    z-index:500;
    background:#171717;
    /* height: 290px */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -10px 20px 0px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -10px 20px 0px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px -10px 10px 0px #000;
}

.textwrap{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    /* top: 40px */
    padding-top:40px; /* added */
}

/* clearfix */
.textwrap:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.content,
.divider,
.content2,
.contentspace {
    text-align:center;
    float: left;
}
.divider{
    /* height: 200px */
    width: 24%;
    float: left;
    /* display:inline-block; */
    margin: 0 1% 1% 0;
}
.divider img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.content,
.content2 {
    /*  height:200px; */
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1% 1% 0;
}
.contentspace{
    width: 20%;
    /* display:inline-block; */
    margin: 0 1% 1% 0;
   
}

/*---------------------------- Footer ----------------------------*/
.footerwrap{
    position:relative;
    /* top:460px; */
    width:100%;
    z-index:501;
    clear:both;
}
.foottxt{
    width:100%;
    height:26px;    
    text-align: center;
    background:#333;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    padding:15px 0;
    font-size:0.5em; /* typo vw */
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:200;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Home</title>
        <!--===================================================css links===================================================!-->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600,500,400,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,900,100,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--===================================================Header===================================================!-->
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="headerwrap">
                <div class="social">
                    <a href="www.facebook.com"><img class="move" src="images/deviant.png"></a>
                    <a href="www.facebook.com"><img class="move" src="images/yt.png"/></a>
                    <a href="www.facebook.com"><img class="move" src="images/fb.png"/></a>
                </div><!--close social!-->
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src="images/logo.png" />
                    </div><!--close logo-->
                </div><!--close header!-->
                <div class="menu">
                    <ul class="menutxt">
                        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="manga.html">CONTACT</a></li>                 
                    </ul>
                </div><!--close menu!-->
            </div><!--close headerwrap!-->
            <!--===================================================Fader===================================================!-->
            <div class="fadewrapper">
                <div class="fader">
                    <img class="bottom" src="images/dsas.png"/>
                    <img class="top" src="images/dsa.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--===================================================Content===================================================!-->
            <div class="contentwrap">      
                <div class="textwrap">
                    
                    <div class="contentspace">
                    </div><!--close contentspace!-->
                    <div class="content">
                        <p>Specializations</p>
                        <p>With various skills in branding, multi-media 
                            and advertising I am able to provide fresh and inspiring solutions 
                            for the task given to me. Using various programs such as:</p>
                    </div><!--close content!-->
                    <div class="divider">
                        <img src="images/divide.png"/>
                    </div><!--close divider!-->
                    <div class="content2">
                        <p>Why me?</p>
                        <p>The work I create is reflecting something
                            fresh and exciting in order to meet the clients 
                            needs. About pushing for new and innovative ideas 
                            and pushing for an end result of brand and product growth</p>
                    </div><!--close content2!-->
                    <div class="contentspace">
                    </div><!--close contentspace!-->
                    
                   
                </div><!--close textwrap!-->
                     
            </div><!--close contentwrap!-->
            <!--===================================================Footer===================================================!-->
            <div class="footerwrap">
                <p class="foottxt">Designed and developed by Luke Babich- All Rights Reserved ©2015</p>
            </div><!--close footerwrap!-->
        </div><!--close wrapper!-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks this seems to have solved the problem. I have to readjust the position of my text to go center. But ill play around with that myself. If its not too much to ask what is the function of the clearfix?

Comment: nevermind about the text, just seems to have about 10px of space under the footer I need to remove. But otherwise thank you very much man

Comment: I think I fixed your problem with the 10px below the footer. I removed the margin from .foottxt and set a padding-top and -bottom of 15px. There was also a typo (see comment in stylesheet).

Comment: yea thats prefect. Thanks a mill for the help man. Was getting frustrated with that damn footer ^^

Comment: You are welcome ;) Clearfix: When you use floats, every(!) element after the floating element will float around it. To stop this, you need to clear the floats. This is achieved by adding "clear:both" to the last child to the surrounding element. You can use .textwrap:after{content:""; display: table; clear: both;} like I did in the stylesheet or you can add a <div style="clear:both;"></div> as last element in .textwrap. The first approach is more elegant, the result is basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when I have a complex site whose CSS I'm trying to unravel, I try to reduce the complexity by playing with a simpler version of the site.

In [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bntvdsvc/), I reproduced your contentwrap and footerwrap classes with some of the irrelevant details removed (you'll have to scroll down to see them because of the positioning that is set on them). As you can see, the footer overlaps the content due to the `position: relative` and `top` properties.

In [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bntvdsvc/1/), the footer moves down as the content grows (check for yourself by changing the `height` property). I removed the `position: relative`, `top`, and `z-index` properties to do this.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need do not position every block with `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;`. It breaks the normal content flow and the real height of the content.
2. If you'll fix your positioning and get normal height of your wrapper, then you can make a sticky footer (if it has fixed height). This footer will be at the very bottom of the page despite the content height.

There is an example ([from CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)), there is a page with footer that has 142px height.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -142px;
}

.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.site-footer,
.page-wrap:after {
  height: 142px;
}

.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">

  Content!

</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>
```